# Gradle tokens from a properties file

Tags: java, spring, gradle, ant, build

I'm trying to configure a spring application that has some tokens on the configuration xml, like:

```
... <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.databasePlatform}" /> ...
```

These tokens worked on an Ant build with build.properties and now I'm trying to make this substitution using gradle. I tried to use ReplaceTokens but now I think that expand would be more suitable but I can get it work. I'm using processResources task:

```
processResources { expand(project.properties) }
```

But the whe I run the build it still complains about the missing placeholder:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.databasePlatform' in string value "${hibernate.databasePlatform}"
```

Is there anything that I had missed?